# How to add custom argument in Spring controller method argument (like: @RequestParam, Model)?

Tags: spring-mvc

This is a typical Spring controller method.

```
public ResponseEntity<RestApiResponse<OTPResponse>> sendOtp(HttpServletRequest request) {
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) request.getSession().getAttribute(SessionKey.USER_DETAILS);
        // Do some work
        //...
}
```

To get the `username` I have to copy the bellow line over and over again in every other controller method.

```
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) request.getSession().getAttribute(SessionKey.USER_DETAILS);
```

Can I do this as follows ?

```
// @UserDetails is some kind of imaginary annotation 
public ResponseEntity<RestApiResponse<OTPResponse>> sendOtp(@UserDetails UserDetails userDetails) {
        userDetails.getUsername();
        // Do some work
        //....
}
```

Can I intercept the request, get the userDetails from request and inject that as controller method argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept requests and do it yourself, however `spring-security` already have such feature. It is called `@AuthenticationPrincipal`.

You can use it as follow:

```
@GetMapping
String hello(@AuthenticationPrincipal java.security.Principal principal) {
    return principal.getName();
}
```

If having a `Principal` isn't enough for your usecase, `User` also works:

```
@GetMapping
String hello(@AuthenticationPrincipal org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user) {
    return user.getUsername();
}
```

You can even inject your custom user details this way if you want.

Please have a look at [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipal.html).

Answer (score 2):

you can use below code as util method

```
public UserDetails getUser(){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
        return (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Another way of doing same.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)   
 public ModelAndView anyMethodNameGoesHere(Principal principal) {
        final String loggedInUserName = principal.getName();

 }
```

Comment: Nice one! The only drawback that this works only with `Principal`.